# The time presented by Calendar Instance on Android is different than the one shown in the device

Tags: android, time

I am doing an application which is to set time on the TextView. I am making the default view by showing it on the TextView in the beginning from Caldenar instance. In my following app when I show the time, it is different (I tried it on two devices, and it is different on both). However, the date works fine.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    static EditText DateEdit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DateEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        DateEdit.setText(minute + ":" + hour + " " + day+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+year);

        DateEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showTruitonDatePickerDialog(v);
                showTruitonTimePickerDialog(v);

            }
        });
    }

    public void showTruitonDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }

    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            // Do something with the date chosen by the user
            DateEdit.setText(DateEdit.getText() + " " + day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
        }
    }

    public void showTruitonTimePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }

    public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                    DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
        }

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            // Do something with the time chosen by the user
            DateEdit.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
        }
    }

}
```

Any ideas how to improve it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How are the dates / times different? Any pattern in the difference?

Comment: No pattern, date is correct. Time is simply different. On my friend's device the difference was 5 hours, on mine 9 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In default settings you have first minute printed and then hours